# parallelize pandas column update

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing

I need to update the column of pandas dataframe based on the processing of a list of selected values (`df0['parcels'].values` in code below). The code works well but is long because the list of selected values is rather long with 45000 values. This code needs 5 hours to complete the task.

As processing on each selected value is independant. I would like to try to parallelize it for improving the speed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt as edt

for i in df0['parcels'].values:
    y, x = np.where(parcels == i)
    tmp = parcels[np.min(y) - 5:np.max(y) + 6, np.min(x) - 5:np.max(x) + 6]
    dst = edt(tmp, sampling=r_parcels)
    par = tmp[dst <= 20]
    par = par[par != -9999]
    mod, cnt = ss.mode(par)
    df['parcels'] = df['parcels'].replace(i, mod[0])
```

Comment: could we have duplicate parcel values that may be overlapped on different iterations?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: no, each value in "df0['parcels'].values" is already unique. Each value of _df0['parcels'].values_ is 1-to-3 pixels, and the search range (_par = tmp[dst <= 20]_) makes a value from _df0['parcels'].values_ cannot be the mode from another value from _df0['parcels'].values_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Pool** provided in **multiprocessing** for parallelisation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt as edt

import multiprocessing as mp

def func(i): # change the body of the loop to function
    y, x = np.where(parcels == i)
    tmp = parcels[np.min(y) - 5:np.max(y) + 6, np.min(x) - 5:np.max(x) + 6]
    dst = edt(tmp, sampling=r_parcels)
    par = tmp[dst <= 20]
    par = par[par != -9999]
    mod, cnt = ss.mode(par)
    return (df['parcels'].replace(i, mod[0]))

num_workers = mp.cpu_count()  
pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)
df['parcels'] = pool.map(func,df0['parcels'].values) # specify the function and arguments to map 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

You can also use **pool.map_async()** or **pool.apply_async()** since **map()** is blocking. In general logic for parallelisation remains the same.

Comment: thank you it is exactly what I want. I understand a little bit more how to do multiprocessing.